# Entity framework: add info to relational tables but keep EF object format

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

If I have 3 tables:

> **Customer**
>  CustID
>  Name
>  Email
>
> **List**
>  ListID
>  Title
>
> **CustomersLists**
>  CustID
>  ListID

Entity Framework makes it very easy to grab lists of a customer.

```
db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Bob").Lists
```

I need save a timestamp of the creation of the relational table so I can see when the customer was added to a list.

I don't want to add a column 'timestamp' to the relational table because it will mess with the intuitive LINQ functionality, as the table `CustomersLists` appears instead of `Customer.Lists`.

I have about 12 tables that need to have this timestamp, most of which don't have many to many relationships. Just fishing to see if anyone has a really good solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Do you want still to access that timestamp by EF (linq)? Or is this just some logging property, which should stay only in DB.

Comment: I don't think i need to query it in any way, so it can just sit in the DB.

Comment: Then add the column to the database and set the default value to `getdate()` but don't map it in the EF model.

Comment: thanks! exactly the solution i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not map the `timestamp` in EF mapping. And set the default value for that `timestamp` column on database layer to: `getDate()`. It will set it to current "datetime" on insert.